# How to migrate big folder from one Google Drive to another

Tags: google-drive, synchronization, migrate-data

My GDrive account is too full: 172 GB. Since I cannot purchase 200 GB subscription (there are only 100 GB or 1TB). I decided to balance out some big folders to my second google account — all eventually to pay on both for 100 GB subscription.

There 2 ways to do it:

1. to download and reupload all files. But it takes days!
2. to share folders and transfer them, so that space is counted towards second account and not the first one

What caveats could be with the second way? How to do it so that no data is lost.